# console.log draw counts of the polygon in WebGL

Tags: webgl, webgl2

How to console.log the polygon count in WebGL, where I want the check the reference of the polygon count before culling and after culling. I'm new to WebGL where I'm analyzing the culling concepts where I want to check the count of the polygons before and culled.

Kindly, help me out! Thanks in advance.

Here's the sample code

```
 (function(global) {

  /*
  * Constants, State, and Main
  * www.programmingtil.com
  * www.codenameparkerllc.com
  */
  var KEYPRESS_SPEED = 0.2;
  var IMAGES = [
    {name:"stainglass", src:"/images/txStainglass.bmp"},
    {name:"crate", src:"/images/txCrate.bmp"},
  ];

  var state = {
    gl: null,
    mode: 'render',
    ui: {
      dragging: false,
      mouse: {
        lastX: -1,
        lastY: -1,
      },
      pressedKeys: {},
    },
    animation: {},
    app: {
      animate: true,
      eye: {
        x:2.,
        y:2.,
        z:5.,
        w:1.,
      },
      fog: {
        color: new Float32Array([0.5,0.5,0.5]),
        dist: new Float32Array([60, 80]),
        on: false,
      },
      light: {
        ambient:  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2],
        diffuse:  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
        position: [1.0, 2.0, 1.7],
      },
      objects: [],
      textures: {},
    },
    eyeInArray: function() {
      return [this.app.eye.x, this.app.eye.y, this.app.eye.z, this.app.eye.w];
    }
  };

  glUtils.SL.init({ callback:function() { main(); } });

  function main() {
    state.canvas = document.getElementById("glcanvas");
    state.overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    state.ctx = state.overlay.getContext("2d");
    state.gl = glUtils.checkWebGL(state.canvas, {
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    });
    initCallbacks();
    initShaders();
    initGL();
    initCanvasTexture();
    initState();
    glUtils.initTextures(IMAGES, state.app.textures, function() {
      draw();
      if (state.app.animate) {
        animate();
      }
    });
  }

  /*
  * Primitives and Objects
  * www.programmingtil.com
  * www.codenameparkerllc.com
  */
  // Create a cube
  function Cube(opts) {
    var opts = opts || {};
    this.id = saKnife.uuid();
    this.opts = opts;
    this.gl = opts.gl;
    this.programs = opts.programs;

    // Vextex positions
    // v0-v1-v2-v3 front
    // v0-v3-v4-v5 right
    // v0-v5-v6-v1 up
    // v1-v6-v7-v2 left
    // v7-v4-v3-v2 down
    // v4-v7-v6-v5 back
    this.attributes = {
      aColor: {
        size:4,
        offset:0,
        bufferData: new Float32Array([
          1, 0, 1, 1,   1, 0, 1, 1,   1, 0, 1, 1,  1, 0, 1, 1,
          1, 1, 0, 1,   1, 1, 0, 1,   1, 1, 0, 1,  1, 1, 0, 1,
          1, 0, 0, 1,   1, 0, 0, 1,   1, 0, 0, 1,  1, 0, 0, 1,
          0, 1, 0, 1,   0, 1, 0, 1,   0, 1, 0, 1,  0, 1, 0, 1,
          0, 1, 1, 1,   0, 1, 1, 1,   0, 1, 1, 1,  0, 1, 1, 1,
          0, 0, 1, 1,   0, 0, 1, 1,   0, 0, 1, 1,  0, 0, 1, 1
        ]),
      },
      aNormal: {
        size:3,
        offset:0,
        bufferData: new Float32Array([
          0.0, 0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
          1.0, 0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
          0.0, 1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 1.0, 0.0,   0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
         -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,  -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
          0.0,-1.0, 0.0,   0.0,-1.0, 0.0,   0.0,-1.0, 0.0,   0.0,-1.0, 0.0,
          0.0, 0.0,-1.0,   0.0, 0.0,-1.0,   0.0, 0.0,-1.0,   0.0, 0.0,-1.0
        ]),
      },
      aPosition: {
        size:3,
        offset:0,
        bufferData: new Float32Array([
          1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,   1.0,-1.0, 1.0,
          1.0, 1.0, 1.0,   1.0,-1.0, 1.0,   1.0,-1.0,-1.0,   1.0, 1.0,-1.0,
          1.0, 1.0, 1.0,   1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
         -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,
         -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,   1.0,-1.0,-1.0,   1.0,-1.0, 1.0,  -1.0,-1.0, 1.0,
          1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,-1.0,   1.0, 1.0,-1.0
       ]),
     },
     aSelColor: {
       size:4,
       offset:0,
       bufferData: undefined,
     },
     aTexCoord: {
       size:2,
       offset:0,
       bufferData: new Float32Array([
         1.0, 1.0,   0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0,
         0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0,   1.0, 1.0,
         1.0, 0.0,   1.0, 1.0,   0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0,
         1.0, 1.0,   0.0, 1.0,   0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0,
         0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0,   1.0, 1.0,   0.0, 1.0,
         0.0, 0.0,   1.0, 0.0,   1.0, 1.0,   0.0, 1.0
       ]),
     },
    };
    this.indices = new Uint8Array([
      0, 1, 2,   0, 2, 3,
      4, 5, 6,   4, 6, 7,
      8, 9,10,   8,10,11,
      12,13,14,  12,14,15,
      16,17,18,  16,18,19,
      20,21,22,  20,22,23
    ]);

    // Functionality
    this.readState = function() {
      this.attributes.aColorBackup = this.attributes.aColor;
      this.attributes.aColor = this.attributes.aSelColor;
      this.state.renderMode = 'read';
    };
    this.drawState = function() {
      this.attributes.aColor = this.attributes.aColorBackup;
      this.state.renderMode = 'render';
    };

    this.draw = function() {
      this.gl.useProgram(this.programs[this.state.renderMode]);
      var uMVPMatrix = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uMVPMatrix');
      var uModelMatrix = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uModelMatrix');
      var uNormalMatrix = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uNormalMatrix');
      var uAmbientLight = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uAmbientLight');
      var uDiffuseLight = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uDiffuseLight');
      var uLightPosition = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uLightPosition');
      var uFogColor = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uFogColor');
      var uFogDist = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uFogDist');
      var uSampler0 = this.gl.getUniformLocation(this.programs[this.state.renderMode], 'uSampler0');
      var mvp = state.mvp;
      this.programs[this.state.renderMode].renderBuffers(this);
      var n = this.indices.length;

      // Model matrix
      var mm = mat4.create();
      if (this.opts.translate) {
        mat4.translate(mm, mm, this.opts.translate);
      }
      if (this.opts.scale) {
        mat4.scale(mm, mm, this.opts.scale);
      }
      if (this.state.angle[0] || this.state.angle[1] || this.state.angle[2]) {
        mat4.rotateX(mm, mm, this.state.angle[0]);
        mat4.rotateY(mm, mm, this.state.angle[1]);
        mat4.rotateZ(mm, mm, this.state.angle[2]);
      }
      this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uModelMatrix, false, mm);

      // MVP matrix
      mat4.copy(mvp, state.pm);
      mat4.multiply(mvp, mvp, state.vm);
      mat4.multiply(mvp, mvp, mm);
      this.gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uMVPMatrix, false, mvp);

      // Fog
      if (state.app.fog.on) {
        this.gl.uniform3fv(uFogColor, state.app.fog.color);
        this.gl.uniform2fv(uFogDist, state.app.fog.dist);
      }

      // Lighting
      if (this.state.renderMode === 'render') {
        this.gl.uniform3f(uDiffuseLight, state.app.light.diffuse[0], state.app.light.diffuse[1], state.app.light.diffuse[2]);
        this.gl.uniform3f(uAmbientLight, state.app.light.ambient[0], state.app.light.ambient[1], state.app.light.ambient[2]);
        this.gl.uniform3f(uLightPosition, state.app.light.position[0], state.app.light.position[1], state.app.light.position[2]);
        var nm = mat3.normalFromMat4(mat3.create(), mm);
        this.gl.uniformMatrix3fv(uNormalMatrix, false, nm);
      }

      // Textures
      if (this.state.hasTexture) {
        this.gl.activeTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE0);
        this.gl.bindTexture(this.gl.TEXTURE_2D, state.app.textures[this.opts.texture]);
        this.gl.uniform1i(uSampler0, 0);
      }

      // Blending
      if (this.state.hasBlend && this.state.renderMode === 'render') {
        this.gl.blendFunc(this.state.blendSrc, this.state.blendDst);
        this.gl.blendEquation(this.state.blendEquation);
        this.gl.disable(this.gl.CULL_FACE);
      }
      else {
        this.gl.enable(this.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        this.gl.disable(this.gl.BLEND);
        this.gl.depthMask(true);

        // Culling
        this.gl.enable(this.gl.CULL_FACE);
        this.gl.cullFace(this.gl.BACK);
      }

      // Culling
      // this.gl.enable(this.gl.CULL_FACE);
      // this.gl.cullFace(this.gl.FRONT_AND_BACK);
      // this.gl.cullFace(this.gl.FRONT);
      // this.gl.cullFace(this.gl.BACK);

      // Draw!
      this.gl.drawElements(this.gl.TRIANGLES, n, this.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    };

    // Cube Initialization
    this.init = function(_this) {
      var selColor = opts.selColor ? opts.selColor : [0,0,0,0];
      _this.selColor = selColor.map(function(n) { return n/255; });
      var arrays = [
        _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor,
        _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor,
        _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor,
        _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor,
        _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor,
        _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor, _this.selColor,
      ];
      _this.attributes.aSelColor.bufferData = new Float32Array([].concat.apply([], arrays));

      _this.state = {
        angle: opts.angle ? opts.angle : [0,0,0],
        blendEquation: opts.blendEquation ? opts.blendEquation : _this.gl.FUNC_ADD,
        blendSrc: opts.blendSrc ? opts.blendSrc : _this.gl.SRC_ALPHA,
        blendDst: opts.blendDst ? opts.blendDst : _this.gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,
        hasBlend: opts.blend ? true : false,
        hasTexture: opts.texture ? true : false,
        mm: mat4.create(),
        nm: null,
        renderMode: 'render',
      };
    }(this);
  }

  /*
  * Initialization
  * www.programmingtil.com
  * www.codenameparkerllc.com
  */
  function initCallbacks() {
    document.onkeydown = keydown;
    document.onkeyup = keyup;
    state.canvas.onmousedown = mousedown;
    state.canvas.onmouseup = mouseup;
    state.canvas.onmousemove = mousemove;
  }

  function initShaders() {
    var vertexRead   = glUtils.getShader(state.gl.VERTEX_SHADER, glUtils.SL.Shaders.read.vertex),
      fragmentRead = glUtils.getShader(state.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, glUtils.SL.Shaders.read.fragment),
      vertexRender = glUtils.getShader(state.gl.VERTEX_SHADER, glUtils.SL.Shaders.render.vertex),
      fragmentRender = glUtils.getShader(state.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, glUtils.SL.Shaders.render.fragment),
      vertexTex    = glUtils.getShader(state.gl.VERTEX_SHADER, glUtils.SL.Shaders.tex.vertex),
      fragmentTex  = glUtils.getShader(state.gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, glUtils.SL.Shaders.tex.fragment);
    state.programs = {
      read: glUtils.createProgram(vertexRead, fragmentRead),
      render: glUtils.createProgram(vertexRender, fragmentRender),
      texture: glUtils.createProgram(vertexTex, fragmentTex),
    };
  }

  function initGL() {
    state.gl.clearColor(0,0,0,1);
  }

  function initState() {
    state.vm = mat4.create();
    state.pm = mat4.create();
    state.mvp = mat4.create();
    state.app.objects = [
      new Cube({
        blend: true,
        blendDst: state.gl.ONE,
        gl: state.gl,
        programs: {
          render: state.programs.texture,
          read: state.programs.read,
        },
        selColor:[255,254,0,0],
        scale:[0.5,0.5,0.5],
        texture:'stainglass',
      }),
      new Cube({
        gl: state.gl,
        programs: {
          render: state.programs.render,
          read: state.programs.read,
        },
        selColor:[255,255,0,0],
        translate:[3,0,0],
      }),
      new Cube({
        gl: state.gl,
        programs: {
          render: state.programs.render,
          read: state.programs.read,
        },
        selColor:[255,253,0,0],
        scale:[0.5,0.5,0.5],
        translate:[-2, 2, 0],
      }),
      new Cube({
        blend: true,
        blendDst: state.gl.ONE,
        gl: state.gl,
        programs: {
          render: state.programs.texture,
          read: state.programs.read,
        },
        selColor:[255,252,0,0],
        scale:[0.6,0.6,0.6],
        texture:'crate',
        translate:[-2, -2, 2],
        angle: [0,35,0],
      }),
      new Cube({
        gl: state.gl,
        programs: {
          render: state.programs.texture,
          read: state.programs.read,
        },
        selColor:[255,251,0,0],
        scale:[0.2,0.2,0.2],
        texture:'crate',
        translate:[2, 2, 2],
        angle: [75,0,0],
      }),
    ];
  }

  function initCanvasTexture() {
    var texture = state.gl.createTexture();
    var textCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    textCanvas.width = 256;
    textCanvas.height = 256;
    var ctx = textCanvas.getContext('2d');

    // Setup background
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(53, 60, 145, 1.0)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, textCanvas.width, textCanvas.height);

    // Setup font
    ctx.font = '36px bold sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 60, 145, 1.0)';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
    ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(10, 160, 190, 1.0)';
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
    ctx.shadowBlur = 5;

    // Draw out some text
    var text = 'ProgrammingTIL';
    var textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    ctx.fillText(text, (textCanvas.width-textWidth)/2, textCanvas.height/2);

    // Change the font and draw out more text
    ctx.font = '26px bold sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
    text = 'David';
    textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    ctx.fillText(text, (textCanvas.width-textWidth)/2, textCanvas.height/2 - 60);
    text = 'Parker';
    textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
    ctx.fillText(text, (textCanvas.width-textWidth)/2, textCanvas.height/2 + 60);

    // Put the canvas onto the texture object
    state.gl.pixelStorei(state.gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, 1);
    state.gl.bindTexture(state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    state.gl.texImage2D(state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, state.gl.RGBA, state.gl.RGBA, state.gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, textCanvas);
    state.gl.texParameteri(state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, state.gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, state.gl.LINEAR);
    state.gl.texParameteri(state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, state.gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, state.gl.LINEAR);
    state.gl.texParameteri(state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, state.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, state.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    state.gl.texParameteri(state.gl.TEXTURE_2D, state.gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, state.gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    state.app.textures['canvastext'] = texture;
  }

  /*
  * State Management
  * www.programmingtil.com
  * www.codenameparkerllc.com
  */
  function updateOverlay() {
    var msg = "Eye position: ("+state.app.eye.x.toFixed(2)+","+state.app.eye.y.toFixed(2)+","+state.app.eye.z.toFixed(2)+")";
    state.ctx.clearRect(0,0,state.ctx.canvas.width,state.ctx.canvas.height);
    state.ctx.save();
    state.ctx.font = "20px Helvetica";
    state.ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    state.ctx.fillText(msg, 10, 25);
    state.ctx.restore();
  }

  function updateState() {
    if (state.ui.pressedKeys[37]) {
      // left
      state.app.eye.x += KEYPRESS_SPEED;
    } else if (state.ui.pressedKeys[39]) {
      // right
      state.app.eye.x -= KEYPRESS_SPEED;
    } else if (state.ui.pressedKeys[40]) {
      // down
      state.app.eye.y += KEYPRESS_SPEED;
    } else if (state.ui.pressedKeys[38]) {
      // up
      state.app.eye.y -= KEYPRESS_SPEED;
    } else if (state.ui.pressedKeys[90] && !state.ui.pressedKeys[16]) {
      // z
      state.app.eye.z += KEYPRESS_SPEED;
    } else if (state.ui.pressedKeys[90] && state.ui.pressedKeys[16]) {
      // Shift+z
      state.app.eye.z -= KEYPRESS_SPEED;
    }
  }

  /*
  * Rendering / Drawing / Animation
  * www.programmingtil.com
  * www.codenameparkerllc.com
  */
  function animate() {
    state.animation.tick = function() {
      updateOverlay();
      updateState();
      draw();
      requestAnimationFrame(state.animation.tick);
    };
    state.animation.tick();
  }

  function draw() {
    state.gl.clear(state.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | state.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    mat4.perspective(state.pm,
      20, state.canvas.width/state.canvas.height, 1, 100
    );
    mat4.lookAt(state.vm,
      vec3.fromValues(state.app.eye.x,state.app.eye.y,state.app.eye.z),
      vec3.fromValues(0,0,0),
      vec3.fromValues(0,1,0)
    );

    // Note: First you should sort (transparent) objects based on distance -> furthest away first
    // For our purposes, we'll loop through everything twice. Once to draw opaque objects
    // and another for transparent objects.
    state.gl.enable(state.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    state.gl.disable(state.gl.BLEND);
    state.gl.depthMask(true);
    state.app.objects.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (!obj.state.hasBlend) {
        obj.draw();
      }
    });
    // Leave on the depth test!
    // state.gl.disable(state.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    state.gl.enable(state.gl.BLEND);
    state.gl.depthMask(false);
    state.app.objects.forEach(function(obj) {
      if (obj.state.hasBlend) {
        obj.draw();
      }
    });
    state.gl.depthMask(true);
  }

  /*
  * UI Events
  * www.programmingtil.com
  * www.codenameparkerllc.com
  */
  function keydown(event) {
    state.ui.pressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true;
  }

  function keyup(event) {
    state.ui.pressedKeys[event.keyCode] = false;
  }

  function mousedown(event) {
    if (uiUtils.inCanvas(event)) {
      state.gl.disable(state.gl.BLEND);
      state.gl.enable(state.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
      state.gl.depthMask(true);
      state.app.objects.forEach(function(obj) {
        obj.readState();
        draw();
      });
      var pixels = Array.from(uiUtils.pixelsFromMouseClick(event, state.canvas, state.gl));
      var obj2 = uiUtils.pickObject(pixels, state.app.objects, 'selColor');
      if (obj2) {
        state.app.objSel = obj2;
        state.ui.mouse.lastX = event.clientX;
        state.ui.mouse.lastY = event.clientY;
        state.ui.dragging = true;
      }
      state.gl.enable(state.gl.BLEND);
      state.gl.disable(state.gl.DEPTH_TEST);
      state.gl.depthMask(false);
      state.app.objects.forEach(function(obj) {
        obj.drawState();
        draw();
      });
    }
  }

  function mouseup(event) {
    state.ui.dragging = false;
  }

  function mousemove(event) {
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    if (state.ui.dragging) {
      // The rotation speed factor
      // dx and dy here are how for in the x or y direction the mouse moved
      var factor = 10/state.canvas.height;
      var dx = factor * (x - state.ui.mouse.lastX);
      var dy = factor * (y - state.ui.mouse.lastY);

      // update the latest angle
      state.app.objSel.state.angle[0] = state.app.objSel.state.angle[0] + dy;
      state.app.objSel.state.angle[1] = state.app.objSel.state.angle[1] + dx;
    }
    // update the last mouse position
    state.ui.mouse.lastX = x;
    state.ui.mouse.lastY = y;
  }
})(window || this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL has no way to give you the info you seek.

WebGL just looks at clipspace triangles in 2D (the values your shader writes to `gl_Position`). In that 2D space it labels them clockwise or counter-clockwise and then discards triangles that you requested to be culled based on the culling settings.

In order to know how many triangles are drawn (or cullled) you'd need to take the math happening in your shaders related to `gl_Position` and reproduce that math in JavaScript. Then run your data through that math and generate triangle vertices. For any triangle you compute the area

--pseudo code--

```
  area = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    p0 = threeScreenSpaceTriangleVertices[i];
    p1 = threeScreenSpaceTriangleVertices[(i + 1) % 3];
    area += p0.x * p1.y - p1.x * p0.y;
  }
  area *= 0.5;  // not really important
```

If area is positive it's clockwise, if it's negative it's counter clockwise

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not possible out of the box with WebGL.
Face culling (in your case backface culling) works by comparing the orientation of the face with the looking direction of the camera.

Thus you can easily write some code on CPU/JS side to compute the number of faces displayed when culling is enabled.

To do so, create at render time a loop over all your cubes faces. Get the normal vectors of the face, transform it with the normal matrix (world inverse transposed) and the view matrix and finally normalize it. At this point you have the normal vector transformed in eye space.

Then compute the dot product with the eye looking vector (0,0,-1) (already normalized). The result is the cosine of the angle between normal and camera.

If the sign is negative, the camera is looking at the front of the face and you can increase the draw count. It it's positive, the camera sees the back of the face and you can discard this one.

```
// In pseudo GLSL code (write it on JS side)
vec3 normalEyeSpace = normalize(viewMatrix * worldInverseTranspose * aNormal)
float dir = dot(normalEyeSpace, vec3(0.0, 0.0, -1.0)
if (dir < 0) drawCount++
```

Comment: WebGL has no concept of camera. It just looks at things in clipspace (2d) to decide whether or a triangle is clockwise or counter-clockwise

Comment: Yes indeed it's only a math thing. I convert the normals into eye space where the viewer is only a vector along the view axis. Do you think it's wrong?

Comment: It's wrong if the user is not using nomals or if they are using them an unusual way. My point is WebGL doens't understand normals or matrices. It just looks at what you write to `gl_Position`. It doesn't know what data or math you used to set it.

Comment: I'm assuming there is a normal attribute and the view and normal matrices computed. Your solution is not dependant on the user implementation, and thus always working. Definitely better, thank you for the explanation